# Errors in kube-apiserver and proxy logs

Tags: kubernetes, kube-apiserver

having such errors in kube-apiserver logs:

```
E0528 13:38:38.762192       1 upgradeaware.go:310] Error proxying data from client to backend: read tcp 192.168.2.151:6443-&gt;192.168.2.151:35760: read: connection reset by peer
```

Checked proxy pods and there are errors as well:

```
E0522 14:30:58.168296       1 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/client/informers/informers_generated/internalversion/factory.go:129: Failed to list *core.Service: Get https://192.168.2.151:6443/api/v1/services?limit=500&amp;resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 192.168.2.151:6443: connect: connection refused
```

Kubernetes v1.11.1

Also I noticed that kube-apiserver memory consumption is constantly growing and leads to a OOM on master node? Anyone faced with such an issues?

Answer (score 0):

There was a known performance issue with etcd2 backend and it was fixed in k8s v1.12.1.

So, either upgrade to 1.12+ version or migrate your cluster to use etcd3

https://coreos.com/blog/migrating-applications-etcd-v3.html